# VS Code: Persistent R or Python sessions over SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I work with R and Python remotely over SSH using VS Code.

I sometimes want to retain R/Python variables in memory even after I disconnect from the server, and pick up the same R/Python sessions where I left off the day before.

Is there any way I could achieve this using VS Code?

The remote server is running Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to figure out how to do this is to first open a `tmux` terminal and then start `R` from within the `tmux` terminal.

Install tmux on the server, then you can open a `bash` terminal from within vscode and type `tmux new -s SESSION_NAME`
Then from within that tmux session type `R`
Now when you want to close your laptop but keep whatever running on the server, close the tmux window with the keystroke `Ctl+b` then `d`.
Now when you want to access the session again you open a bash terminal and type `tmux a -t SESSION_NAME` and then you're right back where you left off

Comment: Thanks! I've had this suggested to me before, but if I'm not mistaken this doesn't allow you to run code interactively (e.g. execute code with Cmd/Ctrl+Enter), only by copy-pasting, right? I later abandoned VS Code (with this being one of the reasons), so I honestly don't remember how well this solution works.

Comment: It works with Command+Enter!! I was just using it as so today. I forget if I had to do other configuration to get it to work that way. I'd recommend trying it out and seeing if it will work, and if not I'd be happy to help point you towards resources. Another recommendation is to add `set -g mouse on` in `~/.tmux.conf` so that you can just scroll with your mouse or trackpad like a normal terminal. I just implemented it yesterday and it works great.